# How to add SyncTex support for evince (or Okular) and LaTeXing for forward and backward navigation between source and pdf

Tags: pdf, viewers, sublime-text, ide, evince

I'm currently using LaTeXing in sublime text 3. Unfortunately I couldn't find a proper solution for enabling forward and backward synctex between source and pdf. The LaTeXing uses evince (on Linux).

[LaTeXing setting page](http://docs.latexing.com/stable/settings.html#SyncTeX%20support)

Comment: `okular` has a setting for 'Editor'. For Kile, for example, it uses the incantation `kile --line %l` but there is also a `Custom Text Editor` option. I guess you need to know the equivalent option to pass `sublime` on the command line. Plus I'm not familiar with `evince`.

Comment: @cfr, thanks. evince is probably the same but I couldn't figure it out how to add the option in LaTeXing setting. It seems no option is supported. Instead they might edit latexmk to do the task, for backward synctex I also didn't see any option/preferences in evince to modify it for backward synctex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools), backward and forward search works great for me.

> (Ubuntu - Texlive -  Sublime Text 3 - Evince)

Comment: Yeah, but I think LaTeXing is also capable of doing such, but unfortunately I've find out a solution yet. So currently LaTeXTools is the alternative solution...

Answer (score 2):

The following set-up also works for Latexing.

First, use Okular to display the pdf. For this, move okular up in the `pdf_viewer_order` setting of Latexing. For example,

```
"pdf_viewer_order" : [
    // Linux
    "okular"
],
```

At this point the `Latexing: Open PDF` command should open okular with the right pdf. Now change the options in okular to use sublime as the editor: under `Settings -> Configure Okular -> Editor` choose `Custom Text Editor` and modify the command to

```
PATH TO SUBLIME/sublime_text %f:%l:%c
```

Now `Shift + Left click` should open sublime at the right position.